# netcat forwarding and listening

Tags: shell-script, netcat

I am listening on a port for logs coming from a device, then I used `netcat` to redirect those logs to a text file whenever a log is available on the device and all this to happen in the background using this command (everything works perfect):

```
nohup nc -kulp <PORT> > <TEXT FILE> &
```

Now, I am trying to write down a script that will re-run the process above every time listening or forwarding is paused or stopped due to device upgrade or reboot that interupts the process.

My question is how to check if `netcat` is still listening and forwarding logs coming from port. I cannot use any program other than `netcat` for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to open a new netcat process on the same port as you did for the first time

```
nohup nc -kulp <PORT> > <TEXT FILE> &
```

if it was failed to open, it means your previous netcat is still running or otherwise it will just open a connection if it was not.

Do the same on the sending part as you did on the receiving part above.

**Note:** You used single redirection `>` above as it will then overwrite the receiving file whenever you try to reopen the connection, stop better to use double redirection `>>` for appending mode.